# How can my git repo have a master without a master ref?

Tags: git, internals

I've been learning git internals and as I understand it, there should be a `ref` file for every branch with the contents of the file being that branch's tip commit sha1. The `HEAD` file's content in the meantime points (usually) to the ref for the branch you're currently on.

So I'm playing around with my repo and I get this...

```
~/code/git-playground/repo1 $ cat .git/HEAD 
ref: refs/heads/master
~/code/git-playground/repo1 $ find .git -type f | grep master
.git/logs/refs/heads/master
~/code/git-playground/repo1 $ ls .git/refs/heads/
chester-branch
```

so I have `HEAD` pointing to `refs/heads/master`, but that ref file doesn't exist! Only something in `/logs` even mentioning `master`. But I can still switch to and from that branch.

```
~/code/git-playground/repo1 $ git branch
  brad-branch
  chester-branch
* master
~/code/git-playground/repo1 $ git checkout chester-branch
Switched to branch 'chester-branch'
~/code/git-playground/repo1 $ git branch
  brad-branch
* chester-branch
  master
```

So what is going on? According to the git book I should see a file inside of `.git/refs/heads` for each branch but there is nothing there!

Comment: Then it must be in `.git/packed-refs`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+where+does+git+store+branches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [ElpieKay noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212736/how-can-my-git-repo-have-a-master-without-a-master-ref#comment100930995_57212736), references can be *packed*.  Packed refs exist in what is today represented as a flat-file database, with one entry per line, in `.git/packed-refs`.

Internally, Git now has an abstraction layer where refs can be represented in any arbitrary way by any given back-end.  There are only two existing back-ends: one that stores refs in files, and one that stores them in the single `packed-refs` file, but I expect that Git will soon enough use a real database to avoid the problems that come up on Windows and MacOS with seemingly-random case-sensitive or case-insensitive branch name behavior.

Comment: Sigh...so git book is wrong...great. The more I learn about git internals the more I think that Linus had no intention of writing a VCS, he just wanted to play with content addressable file systems and kept piling abstractions and optimizations on until a VCS happened to fall out

Comment: It's not so much *wrong* as *hasn't kept up with internal changes*. It's a bit tricky, the line between documenting intended, observable behavior, and internal implementation detail. Note that Linus has not been involved in day-to-day Git since perhaps 2006, though—it's now a core Git team with a lot of input from people who work at GitHub, Bitbucket, and Microsoft...

Comment: Yeah, I get it, I was reading the internals chapter directly and going "well yeah, CAFS is cool but...that's not exactly a great fit for a version control system thats all about small changes over time"